# Short-term rentals in Italy?

Tags: residency, italy, rental

I intend on settling in Italy for a short period (<3 months). From what I've read, it's very hard to actually find people that are willing to rent their apartments for such short stays. Why is that?

Is it possible to rent apartments (with a contract) and be registered as a resident in the municipality for a stay of say, three months? I've had no problems with these sorts of rentals here in France; is Italy different? How hopeless is my situation?

I know there are a lot of questions but I believe their answers will complement each other into a single answer.

Comment: Italy is a difficult country and Italians are not open-minded, and it is quite difficult that a foreigners might have a specific request fulfilled. I believe that he fears that you won't pay him, because here landlords might incur in some scenarios in which the rentee doesn't want to pay the rent and at the same time it is inconvenient for the landlord to file a lawsuit against him, especially for 3 months only. He might just lose money in the process by taking you to court, hence they feel safer not to do that.

Comment: It's not that you are a bad person, it's that Italy is strange, it's a glass bell, things go in their own fashion. Every country has its own strangenesses, but trust me, here it's an other level all together.

Comment: To give you another idea on how the country works, a employer may hire a lawyer to defend himself against a worker which he hasn't paid because it's more convenient to him, and on top of that he might rely also on the poverty of the worker who could not afford a lawyer, and make him leave the case. It is unrelated, but it gives an idea on how things work here